# How do I make netcat receive UDP packets from any host?

Tags: bash, udp, netcat

Is there a way to make `netcat` receive UDP packets from any ip:port? I don't want it to bind to a specific host as the first packet comes.

I can consider alternatives, but they have to be bash friendly (allow piping).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LucasKauffman just dump whatever udp packet arrives to a specific port. I cannot use tcpdump as I don't have root privileges on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *some* `nc` versions, it's possible to specify a `-k` option:

> -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.  It is an error to use this
>   option without the -l option.  **When used together with the -u option,
>   the server socket is not connected and it can receive UDP datagrams
>   from multiple hosts.**

Answer (score 0):

If you you are doing this on Linux then you could set up an iptables rule using the REDIR target.  Just redirect all UDP traffic to a single port and then listen on that port with netcat.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible without root permission.

Comment: I don't need to listen UDP packets that arrive to any port. The target ip port is specified, but not the source. This is possible as a normal user, and as a side note I've alredy written a minimal c program that can do it, but I asked because I lost half an hour trying to get `nc` to do it, and now I want to know if it's totally impossible with common shell utilities.

Comment: aaah so you are trying to connect to a port?

Comment: no, the source port will change at every packet.